# ExtJs:How to set a width in percentage?

Tags: extjs, width, percentage

My test code shows below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.onReady(function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
            id: "Button",
            renderTo: Layer
        });
    });

    function SetPixelWidth() {
        var button = Ext.getCmp("Button");
        button.setWidth(200);
    }

    function SetPercentageWidth() {
        var button = Ext.getCmp("Button");
        button.setWidth("50%");
    }
</script>

<button onclick="SetPixelWidth()">Set Width(Pixel)</button>
<button onclick="SetPercentageWidth()">Set Width(Percentage)</button>
<div id="Layer" style="width:100%;background:black"></div>
```

> `setWidth(200)` works fine, but "setWidth("50%")" don't take effect.

How to set a width in `percentage` or other units over `pixel`?

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: Check out `Ext.dom.AbstractElement.defaultUnit`.
I'm not sure you can do it what you want.

Comment: I set the defaultUnit to "%" and "button.setWidth(50)", but it also didn't set the button width to 50% of it's layer length.  
  
    Ext.dom.AbstractElement.defaultUnit="%";

Answer (score 1):

[See this post on the Sencha forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?293473-setWidth-to-percentage)

The best you can do in this situation is grab the width of the containing object. So something like

```
function SetPercentageWidth()
{
    var button = Ext.getCmp("Button");
    button.setWidth(button.ownerCt.getWidth() * .5);
}
```